# why I get KeyError when I extract data with specific keywords from CSV file using python?

Tags: python-3.x, csv, parsing

I am trying to use below code to get posts with specific keywords from my csv file but I keep getting KeyErro "Tag1"

```
 import re
 import string
 import pandas as pd
 import openpyxl
 import glob
 import csv
 import os
 import xlsxwriter
 import numpy as np

 keywords = {"agile","backlog"}
        # all your keywords

 df = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\ferr1982\Desktop\split1_out.csv", 
  error_bad_lines=False)#, sep="," , 
  encoding="utf-8")
  output = pd.DataFrame(columns=df.columns)

 for i in range(len(df.index)):
    #if (df.loc[df['Tags'].isin(keywords)]):
    if any(x in ((df['Tags1'][i]),(df['Tags2'][i]),  (df['Tags3'][i] ), 
      (df['Tags4'][i]) , (df['Tags5'][i]))  for x in keywords):
       output.loc[len(output)] = [df[j][i] for j in df.columns]

            output.to_csv("new_data5.csv", incdex=False)
```

Comment: Does split1_out.csv have a column named Tags1?

Comment: Yes, but there were a space just before it. Have fixed it already. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, it turned to be that there is a little space before "Tags" column in my CSV file !
it is working now after I added the space to the name in the code above.